# Save Chinese characters with Spring-MVC / Java

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to save Chinese characters from a form submit into the database.

I've set the contentType on the jsp via

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

I've also set this tag inside the  of the jsp:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

However, when I submit the form, my controller sees a different character than what I entered.

I am entering the character 我 and seeing æ?? in the controller.  When the data redisplays on the page, it shows the same wrong character (æ??).

Why isn't the controller getting the correct character?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298252/jsp-page-encoding-problem/4298286#4298286

Answer (score 3):

Declare a CharacterEncodingFilter in your web.xml file before any other filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In your jsp file try adding this at the very start of the file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: The `language` and `contentType` parts are by the way superfluous here. It are already the defaults. Just `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>` is sufficient.

Comment: This will convert data to ?(question mark) only, i am using sring, hibernate and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers will respect the character set you've specified in the page or the form.  Spring provides a filter, the [CharacterEncodingFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html), that can add a character encoding or force a particular encoding, as the request comes in and before it hits the controller.

Comment: I've set the filter using Spiff's response in http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=14063.

Answer (score 0):

Add an accept-charset attribute to your form:

```
<form method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" ... >
```

This tells the browser to submit your form contents as UTF-8 to the server.

Comment: This attribute is marked optional by HTML spec and ignored by practically all browsers when the charset is present in the response header which is then preferred. Don't use it.